# HTML Table Header using rowspan

Tags: html, html-table

```
<html>
<body>

<TABLE border="1" ">

<CAPTION><EM>A test table with merged cells</EM></CAPTION>

<TR><TH rowspan="2"><TH colspan="2"> Average
    <TH rowspan="2">Red<BR>eyes </TH>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TH>height</TH><TH>weight</TH>
</TR>
<TR> 
  <TD>1.9<TD>0.003<TD>40%</TD>
</TR>
<TR> 
  <TD>1.7<TD>0.002<TD>43%</TD>
</TR>

</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the output with first element of header as blank

```
  A test table with merged cells
/-----------------------------------------\
|          |      Average      |   Red    |
|          |-------------------|  eyes    |
|          |  height |  weight |          |
|-----------------------------------------|
|  1.9     | 0.003   |   40%    |         |
|-----------------------------------------|
|  1.7     | 0.002   |   43%    |         |
\-----------------------------------------/
```

Expected output

```
  A test table with merged cells
/----------------------------- \
|      Average      |   Red    |          
|-------------------|  eyes    |          
|  height |  weight |          |          
|------------------------------|
|  1.9     | 0.003   |   40%   |          
|------------------------------|
|  1.7     | 0.002   |   43%   |          
\------------------------------/
```

Comment: And your question would be..?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove the extra TH in your code

http://jsfiddle.net/yqQsP/

```
<html>
<body>

<TABLE border="1" >

<CAPTION><EM>A test table with merged cells</EM></CAPTION>

<TR>
    <TH colspan="2"> Average</TH>
    <TH rowspan="2">Red<BR>eyes </TH>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TH>height</TH><TH>weight</TH>
</TR>
<TR> 
  <TD>1.9<TD>0.003<TD>40%</TD>
</TR>
<TR> 
  <TD>1.7<TD>0.002<TD>43%</TD>
</TR>

</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

While [nauphal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10244877/#answer-10245001) has already addressed your problem, I just wanted to make some suggestions regarding your HTML structure.

First, upper-case isn't mandatory (HTML's case-insensitive), though should you ever switch to XHTML lower-case ***is*** mandatory (and, frankly, looks a little nicer too).

Second, because a `tbody` element is always inserted by the browser (I'm not sure about all clients, but certainly visual web-clients) if there isn't one present already, it's usually best to wrap those elements that represent the 'body' of the table in a `tbody` yourself, that way you can assign the `th` element-rows to a `thead`, which increases semantics a little (I'm not sure how useful that is, but every little helps).

Third, remember to close your tags:

```
<TR> 
  <TD>1.9<TD>0.003<TD>40%</TD>
</TR>
```

Should, really, be:

```
<TR> 
  <TD>1.9</TD><TD>0.003</TD><TD>40%</TD>
</TR>
```

Again, it's not mandatory (in HTML 4, I believe), but it reduces the scope for errors introduced by having extra, un-closed, start-tags around your mark-up.

Fourth, and this is just nit-picking, possibly, if you're wanting to style the whole of the `caption` as emphasized text it's easier to avoid inserting extra mark-up and just style the `caption` directly.

That said, here's my version of your table and some CSS:

```
<table>
    <caption>A test table with merged cells</caption>
    <theader>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Average</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Red Eyes</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>height</th>
            <th>weight</th>
        </tr>
    </theader>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1.9</td>
            <td>0.003</td>
            <td>40%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>0.002</td>
            <td>43%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
caption {
    font-style: italic;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0.2em;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2GThw/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Change First Row

```
<TR>
    <TH colspan="2"> Average</TH>
    <TH rowspan="2">Red<BR>eyes </TH>
</TR>
```

It will solve the problem